# How do I set the binding port number for a set of IIS websites with an increment value using PowerShell?

Tags: loops, powershell, iis

I have an IIS back end server with many websites. I just created these sites using powershell. I need to set the binding port for each website to a unique number (starting at 9200) for the proxy. I am trying to find a way to script this out, but I am having a hard time trying to find a solution to this one. Currently I have a list of websites in a text file I want to set the binding port for. Right now this is what I have:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$endpoints = Get-Content C:\scripts\endpoints.txt

foreach ($number in 9200..9310)
{
    foreach ($site in $endpoints)
        {
    Set-WebBinding -Name '$site' -BindingInformation "*:80:" -PropertyName Port -Value $number
    }
  }
```

The reason I have the first foreach loop is to get the port numbers from 9200-9310 since I have 110 websites in total. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having with your script?

Comment: Basically I want each site in the list to be assigned a unique port number (9200-9310). Instead of assigning a port number to each site the script is trying to bind each website to every port number (9200-9310).

Comment: Inside your number loop you are looping over each site. Effectively for port 9200 you are assigning every site. Then 9201: every site. 9202: every site.... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is your two `foreach` loops. You have your second `foreach` loop inside of the one containing the port numbers. Therefore, your first loop starts at `$number = 9200` and then sets EACH `$site` equal to the port held in your `$number` variable at that time and then exits that loop and increments the port number and starts again.

Here is something I came up with that I believe will solve your problem.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$endpoints = Get-Content C:\scripts\endpoints.txt

$ports = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
[int] $port = 9200
[int] $counter = 0

while($port -le 9310) {
  $ports.Add($port)
  $port++
}

foreach ($site in $endpoints)
{
   Set-WebBinding -Name '$site' -BindingInformation "*:80:" -PropertyName Port -Value $ports[$counter]
   $counter++
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for KangarooRIOT. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TaylorDuncan could you please mark the question answered then? Glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I just did.